# TextBox in WPF TreeView not updating source

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, textbox, treeview

I cannot tell if I fundamentally don't understand something here, or have just done something silly.

I have a tree view with two types of templates.

1. Nodes that are HierarchicalDataTemplate with a TextBlock
2. Leaves that are DataTemplate with a TextBlock and a TextBox3.

The binding from source is working fine in all cases and reading the Name or Name & Value properties from the underlying classes, and updating if from any changes from the code behind.

Both the TreeNode and TreeLeaf class implement INotifyPropertyChanged

However the binding of the TextBox.text property back to the TreeLeaf.Value property (with its getter) does not seem to work.

**XAML**

```
<TreeView  Name="ItemsTree" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="detailMark">#FFA1A9B3</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="detailMarkBrush" Color="{StaticResource ResourceKey=detailMark}" />
        <Style x:Key="flatTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle  Stroke="{StaticResource ResourceKey=detailMarkBrush}" StrokeThickness="0"/>
                            <TextBox Margin="1" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" BorderThickness="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}">
            </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeLeaf}" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Width="150" Text="{Binding Name, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"/>
                <TextBox Width="150"  Text="{Binding Value, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,  Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=flatTextBox}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

And then code behind for adding the items to the tree

```
ItemsTree.Items.Add(treeRoot)
```

The **TreeLeaf** class

```
Public Class TreeLeaf
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged, IEditableObject

    Private m_Key As String
    Private m_Value As String
    Private m_Parent As TreeNode

    Private temp_Item As TreeLeaf = Nothing
    Private m_Editing As Boolean = False

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Public Sub New()
        m_Key = ""
        m_Value = ""
    End Sub


    Public Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    Public Sub BeginEdit() Implements IEditableObject.BeginEdit
        If Not m_Editing Then
            temp_Item = MemberwiseClone()
            m_Editing = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub EndEdit() Implements IEditableObject.EndEdit
        If m_Editing = True Then
            temp_Item = Nothing
            m_Editing = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub CancelEdit() Implements IEditableObject.CancelEdit
        If m_Editing = True Then
            m_Key = temp_Item.m_Key
            m_Value = temp_Item.m_Value
            m_Editing = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Property Parent As TreeNode
        Get
            Return m_Parent
        End Get
        Set(value As TreeNode)
            m_Parent = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Parent")
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Name As String
        Get
            Return m_Key & " : "
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Property Key As String
        Get
            Return m_Key
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If Not value = m_Key Then
                m_Key = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Key")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Value As String
        Get
            Return m_Value
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If Not value = m_Value Then
                m_Value = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Value")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

I have seen mentions of setting the DataContext but I don't understand how that would apply to this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, unfortunately figured it out.

The style template for the text box was overriding the binding.

The line with TemplateBinding seems to default to a one way from source

```
<TextBox Margin="1" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" BorderThickness="0"/>
```

and it now works if you change it too

```
<TextBox Margin="1" Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" BorderThickness="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to tell from your code whether the binding works or not since the ViewModel code is complicated enough and also depends on the treeview viewmodel code etc...

One way to debug these types of problems is to create a Converter and make it part of the binding that should be debugged. Setting a breakpoint within the Converter will show whether the binding is called as expected when the value in the source or destination has changed. The code for the converter is realy simple:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Windows.Data

Namespace MyApp.Converters
    Public Class DebugConverter
        Inherits IValueConverter

        Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As CultureInfo) As Object
            Return value
        End Function

        Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As CultureInfo) As Object
            Return value
        End Function
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Its integration into a questionable binding is also simple. Add it via its namespace (eg MyApp.Converters) into the XAML:

```
xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:MyApp.Converters"
```

...and create an instance via this statement in the Resource section of your TreeView code listing:

```
<conv:DebugConverter x:Key="DebugConverter"/>
```

...and last but not least integrate the converter into a binding you want to debug:

```
<TextBox
Width="150"
Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=flatTextBox}"
Text="{Binding Value, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}}" />
```

Now, when you set a breakpoint in the Convert and ConvertBack method you should see these methods being invoked when you start the application. If you do not see it in either direction you know the binding is either not working or the value is not being updated and you can then search further for the cause.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately it hasn't got me any further. I can see that the Convert function is being called when the TextBox is being displayed, or I update the value somewhere else in the code behind. But convert back is never called, not on property change, or lose focus. For all intents and purposes I would assume this was a one way binding, apart from the explicitly stating two way.